# Replacing in Notepad++ using regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a cpp file which contains a global array definition but unfortunately, the guy which was writing the define did not used the literals for float values(1.0f instad of 1.0), so I have decided to do that using notepad++. The array definition is as follows (it is really big, like 10000 lines of code):

```
const float ifxColorMap::ifxColorScaleCSTFire[] = 
{
0, 1, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.984314, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.968627, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.952941, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.937255, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.921569, 1,1.0f,
0, 0.905882, 1,1.0f,
...
```

Can anyone please help me with replacing the 0, 0.984314, 1,1.0f, lines with 0, 0.984314f, 1.0f,1.0f using notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two steps:

**Step 1**:

Search `, *1,`

Replace `, 1.0,` (with or without an "f")

**Step 2**:

Search `(\d+\.\d+)(?!f)`

Replace `$1f`

Answer (score 3):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they  have two problems.

- JWZ

You don't need to use a regex here, just two find/replace operations.

1. Copy/paste the array definition to a new document
2. Find/replace all commas with `f,`
3. Find/replace all newlines (could be `\r`, `\r\n` or `\n`, depending on platform & other editor(s) used - you'll have to check for yourself) followed by `0f,` with a newline followed by `0,`. You have to use the "Extended" option for this because of the special characters
4. Copy/paste your array definition back to the original file

Comment: yes. you are right. I just replaced ',f' with ',' and then ',' with 'f,' then everything is working!

Perfect! :D

Comment: You would still end up with `1f,` instead of `1.0f,`. But if you try to replace all `1f,` with `1.0f,`, you'll erroneously replace `0.952941f,` with `0.952941.0f,`. That's where regex helps.

Comment: yeah! now, I faced that problem! I will follow this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed the problem with a small chunk of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("in.txt");
    std::ofstream outFile("out.txt");

    char line[401];
    char buffer[401];
    int bufCounter = 0;
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        inFile.getline(line, 400);
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(line[i] == ',')
            {
                buffer[bufCounter] = '\0';
                if(buffer[bufCounter-1] != 'f')
                {
                    // has dot inside
                    size_t j = 0;
                    for(; j < bufCounter; j++)
                        if(buffer[j] == '.')
                            break;

                    if(j == bufCounter)
                        outFile << buffer << ".0f, ";
                    else
                        outFile << buffer << "f, ";
                }
                else
                    outFile << buffer << ", ";

                bufCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t')
                    ;// Do Nothing
                else
                    buffer[bufCounter++] = line[i];
            }
        }

        outFile << "\n";
    }
}
```